# awsmobile configure -> Error: The header content contains invalid characters

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-mobilehub

Followed below steps:

- I have created IAM user, where that user is attached to a Group and that Group has a policy set as `AdministratorAccess`.
- I have configured `awsmobile`, using `awsmobile configure`, pasted creds from IAM user created above. Changed the region to `us-east-2`
- While executing `awsmobile init`, I'm getting an error as below that contains `us-east-1` as a region, but why.

  `backend awsmobile project creation error
  { NetworkingError: The header content contains invalid characters
  at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:494:11)
  at ClientRequest.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
  at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:173:14)
  at Object.request (http.js:38:10)
  at Object.request (https.js:239:15)
  at features.constructor.handleRequest (C:\Users\manus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\awsmobile-cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\http\node.js:42:23)
  at executeSend (C:\Users\manus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\awsmobile-cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:304:29)
  at Request.SEND (C:\Users\manus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\awsmobile-cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:318:9)
  at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\manus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\awsmobile-cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:101:18)
  at Request.emit (C:\Users\manus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\awsmobile-cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:77:10)
  message: 'The header content contains invalid characters',
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  region: 'us-east-1',
  hostname: 'mobile.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
  retryable: true,
  time: 2018-04-28T15:26:56.753Z`

Below is package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
 "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^2.0.3",
 "aws-amplify": "^0.3.3",
 "aws-amplify-react": "^0.1.43",
 "aws-sdk": "^2.228.1",
 "react": "^16.3.2",
 "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
 "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
},
```

- Node.js version: 8.11.1
- awsmobile version: 1.1.1
- npm version: 6.0.0
- yarn version: 1.6.0
- OS: Windows 10  VSCode: 1.22.2

[Github Issue](https://github.com/aws/awsmobile-cli/issues/117)

Comment: It sounds like you have made a copy/paste error while configuring, perhaps picking up a leading or trailing space that is actually a value like &#160; or ascii null during the content copy operation.  Viewing the config file with a hex editor might help you spot a byte value larger than 0x7F or possibly 0x00.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine now.

I disabled firewall and copied creds using chrome developer tool and it worked. Then I re-enabled the firewall and tried again and it still worked. I thought problem was that I was copying the creds from AWS console itself, but then I tried to create a new user and copied from AWS console instead of chrome developer tool, and it also worked i.e everything is working now.

I also tried to create a new project by following https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-mobile-react-sample#getstarted and it also went well.

So, I can't recreate it now. Not sure what was the issue.